# How to call broadcast receiver in my activity so that when i clicked on button it will activate?

Tags: android

I created the broadcast receiver for incoming call and also register the receiver in the manifest file.  I am newbie so I cannot understand how to call that on my button in my MainActivity

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        String msg = "Phone state changed to " + state;

        if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state)) {
                String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            msg += ". Incoming number is " + incomingNumber;

            // TODO This would be a good place to "Do something when the phone rings" ;-)
            }
            Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you register broadcast receiver in manifest it will automatically starts when app launches but after Android Oreo manifest registered receiver wont work. Instead use context registered receiver.  https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts

Answer (score 0):

If you register the Broadcast  Receiver in the manifest file, then it will automatically gets triggered whenever the event happen.
Instead of that, do the broadcast receiver registration on the button click:

```
btn.setOnClickListener{
   registerReceiver()
}

override fun onStop(){
   fun registerReceiver()
}

private fun registerReceiver(){
  //Do the registration here
}

private fun fun registerReceiver() {
   // Unsubscribe receiver
}
```

For more information:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts

Answer (score 0):

You can Register Receiver with this I did it from my service class....

```
ServiceInstance.registerReceiver(receiverName, choice "if any action");
```

You can UnRegister Receiver with this....

```
ServiceInstance.unregisterReceiver(receiverName);
```